# Spring security filter called twice

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I just realized that the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is called twice when accessing the protected resource /me in my OAuth auth server:

[image]

An abstract of my xml config:

```
<http pattern="/me/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/me/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.hasScope('read')" />
    <!-- Protect the resource with oauth by using the resourceServerFilter-->
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    <request-cache ref="requestCache" />
</http>
```

and

```
<http access-denied-page="/login?authorization_error=true" disable-url-rewriting="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <!-- /secure/** is protected and for users only. Don't allow oauth2 clients to access protected UI pages.
         Put all secured web pages under /secure (e.g. /secure/profile) -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.denyOAuthClient()" />
    <!-- Allow access to everything else -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />

    <form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
        login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login.do" authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <!-- See also LogoutFilterPostProcessor -->
    <logout logout-url="/logout.do" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"  success-handler-ref="lclSessionCookieDeletingLogoutHandler" />
    <anonymous />

    <!-- Allow the usage of oauth web expressions (e.g. '#oauth2.denyOAuthClient()') -->
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    <request-cache ref="requestCache" />
    <csrf token-repository-ref="csrfTokenRepository"/>
    <remember-me services-ref="persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices" key="abcdefg"/>
    <custom-filter ref="forcePasswordResetFilter" before="REQUEST_CACHE_FILTER" />
</http>
```

It seems as if the filters from the second `<http/>` section (e.g. the ForcePasswordResetFilter) are also applied when /me is called - which is not what I'd expect. Any ideas why not only the first `<http/>` section is considered which matches /me/**?

Comment: My guess would be, that in your web.xml you intercept all urls within DelegatingFilterProxy which introduces xml reader to read and instantiate FilterChainProxy instance. So when reader finds "http" it means that all filters defined within <http> will be grouped to SecurityFilterChain. Your first Security chain has pattern "/me**", but the second one - doesn't, only individual filters has, but the latter chain still activated. So when you call first SecurityFilterChain (first <http>), the second one also is applied (second <http>), because the latter one hasn't it's pattern (only it's filters)

Comment: So is there a way to not have the second chain (`<http/>`) being executed for calls to /me? I believe the `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />` in the second `<http/>` kicks in.